# Storing template type to cast Base back down to Derived<T>

Tags: c++, templates

So I have these classes:

```
class Base {

};
template <typename T>
class Derived<T>: public Base {

};

class util {
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void add(Derived<T> arg) {
           vec.push_back(arg);
        } 
        
        void start() {
            //cast back down to Derived<T>
        }
  
   private:
       std::vector<Base> vec;
};
```

In `start()` I want to cast it back down to `Derived<T>` but since the T can be anything, I can't cast it without the type. I'm wondering if there was to store the first element of vec's type information in like a `typedef` or something so that I can use that in `start()`

Comment: Storing the `Derived<T>`s in a `vector<Base>` *slices*: the `Base` subobject of `arg` is copied into `vec` and the rest of it is destroyed. `vec` *doesn't have* any `Derived<T>` objects to downcast. So: 1) this is probably an XY problem; what are you actually trying to do? 2) If you go ahead with this, you probably need to store (smart) *pointers*, not objects, in the vector 3) See `std::type_info` and `std::any`. 4) You can't have a `Derived<T>` without knowing what `T` is at compile time. Period. Perhaps type erasure is in order (look it up on SO, I'm out of characters).

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of the [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4173254/5987) but I don't think it applies in your case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a syntax issue:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived<T>: public Base { // Won't compile, the class name is Derived, and it doesn't suppose to get specialized by T type
};
```

The right way:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base {};
```

For your issue, you don't need to convert it back to the derived type, you just need to make your vector a vector of pointers to Base class (and in the insertion function, accept the Derived type as a reference, to pass it's address to the vector).
**Note:** in the implementation you'll see that I passed a shared_ptr- it's to make the ownership of the address obvious, when you use shared_ptr instead of unsafe pointers in your vector (Thanks to [@idclev463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/idclev-463035818) for the note).

```
class util {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void add(std::shared_ptr<Derived<T>> arg) {
        vec.push_back(arg);
        // vec.push_back(&arg); // In case that you don't use shared_ptr, and pass arg by reference.
    }

    void start() {
        for (auto d : vec) { /* ...  */ }
    }

private:
    // Idea: std::vector<Base*> vec;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec; // For safe memory management
};
```

Comment: probably it should be a vector of smart pointers. In your code it isnt clear who own the elements in the vector and you cannot delete them in `util` because you cannot know whether it was dynamically allocated. `add` should take a smart pointer to make ownership obvious

Comment: @idclev463035818 I always recommend to use smart pointers, but I wanted to make the point here more clearer for the OP. But you are right, I added a note there.

Comment: Even with the shared pointers if Derived<T> has some method, I cant call the method without casting it since Base doesnt have that method defined.

Comment: @Kit it's true, but if this is the case, it's probably an architecture issue. The base is an interface, which allows you to use Polymorphism. If you want just a collection of different types you should consider using variadic functions/templates.